# How to fix a stack overflow error caused by recursive functions? C++

Tags: c++, recursion, graphics, stack-overflow

As titled, I figured a recursive function has caused my program stack overflowing. And the recursive logic is needed, how to fix it?

Code:

```
static bool orient_flip_face(HE *edge)
{
    if(edge->flip == NULL)
        return 1;
    return orient_face(face);
}

static bool orient_face(HEF *face)
{
    assert(face->oriented);
    return orient_flip_face(face->edge);
}

static bool build_HE(he::Mesh_Data *mesh,
                     std::vector<HEV*> *hevs,
                     std::vector<HEF*> *hefs)
{
     // process mesh data
     // ...

     return orient_face(first_face);
}
```

Basically **orient_face** and **orient_flip_face** calling each other back and forth until it's the last vertices. It's fine when I pass a simple mesh, but when I pass the stanford rabbit which has 63690 vertices, it's overflowed.Then I increased **stack reversed size** to **40MB** and it fixed the stack overflow error. But is it a reasonable solution?

Thank you!

Comment: Please show the code. Without code we can only guess, which probably wont help you.

Comment: sorry! Adding it right now

Comment: You could try to convert it to a loop.

Comment: The important distinction is between infinte recursion and large but still finite recursion. Infinite recusion is effectively a logic error. But if the recursion is finite it might be possible to optmise it.

Comment: You can recode that as a simple loop. No need for recursion at all.

Comment: Assuming that the condition `edge->flip == NULL` will ever be true, then the result of the initial call to `orient_face` will *always* be `1`, nothing else will happen with the code shown.

Comment: As for a possible cause of the problem, do you remember to initialize your structures? Also, how many objects do you chain together in your "list"? And finally, the code you show isn't a proper [mcve], especially considering that it contains unrelated errors (in the `orient_flip_face` function, what is `face`?)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Thanks for the suggestion! I will make minimal reproducible example next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is an example of *tail recursion* because the recursive calls are the last thing executed in each function. Tail recursion is easy to transform into a non-recursive loop. The following code is the equivalent to the code you have and doesn't use recursion at all.

```
static bool orient_face(HEF *face)
{
    for (;;)
    {
        assert(face->oriented);
        HE *edge = face->edge;
        if (edge->flip == NULL)
            return 1;
    }
}

static bool build_HE(he::Mesh_Data *mesh,
                     std::vector<HEV*> *hevs,
                     std::vector<HEF*> *hefs)
{
     // process mesh data
     // ...

     return orient_face(first_face);
}
```

As some programmer dude pointed out, the code is effectively a no-op (excepting the assert, but I'm assuming that's just a debugging detail, and not the point of the code). So unless there's something else going on you can delete it completely.

The details matter.

Comment: Wow I solved by taking your suggestion using a while loop to replace recursion! Thank you John!!

Answer (score 1):

You are probably running into huge recursion or even infinite recursion loop. Try checking your base case condition and verify that the recursion stops within a finite limit.

Comment: Thanks! Base case works! It crashed when have 63690 calls.

Comment: Could you add more details in your questions. It's hard to help without knowing further details.

Comment: sure! Just added!